# Why aren't my divs lining up correctly?

Tags: html, css

I am making a webpage with 2 `div`s in a `div`, but the 2 smaller divs aren't lining up, here is an example: [image: example]

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id = "creators" class = "big-part">
    <h3>Creators</h3>

    <div class = "creator_name">
            <h4>FlipFloop</h4>
            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text texttext text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "creator_name">
            <h4>TickTock</h4>
            <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>
        </div>
            <!--<div class = "creator_name">
            <h4>Name</h4>
            <p>Text</p>
        </div>-->

        </div>
```

and my CSS:

```
.creator_name {
    width: 35%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 2% 2%;
}
```

when I use `float: left` : [image: example2]

Comment: Have you checked with the developer tools in your browser?

Comment: Try using `float: left;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
.creator_name {
vertical-align:top;
}
```

jsfiddle link [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/6k8j8mzz/)

Comment: A better answer would also explain _why_ this solution works